# Firebase and GoogleMobileAds not working with eachother In Unity

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, admob, firebase-storage

So i'm having an issue with Getting Firebase to work with GoogleMobileAds In Unity.

I keep getting "Unable to convert classes into dex format" The way you can Duplicate this error is by downloading GoogleMobileAds Here

https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/releases

And Installing the Firebase Storage SDK from the new release.

Any help is much appreciated since i have been looking everywhere for an answer!

Answer (score 0):

Both have newer versions.

Try them out, they no longer conflict.
The problem before was due ro certain ckasses using same names in the jar files. This is not something rhe aveeage user can fix.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/unity-plugins/Firebase-Admob-Unity Maybe a good choose which have combine 
firebase and googleadmob togather with all conflic soled.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)